# Dynamically add dependsOn to the gradle task

Tags: android, gradle

I've a project with many modules (10+). Inside each `build.gradle` file there is a task:

```
task findbugs(type: FindBugs, dependsOn: ':MODULENAME:compileReleaseSources') {
    ignoreFailures = true
    classes = fileTree('build/intermediates/classes/release/')
    source = fileTree('src/main/java/')
    classpath = files()
    ... and so on
}
```

so I wanted to extract this task and create a custom `script.gradle` file with this task and include it to every `build.gradle` using `apply from: script.gradle`.

And here comes the problem, in order for this to work, I need to include the **MODULENAME** to the `dependsOn`. When I had task inside every `build.gradle` there was no problem at all, because I've just hardcoded the corresponding module name (`:app:compileReleaseSources, :firebase:compileReleaseSources`, etc.).

Is there any way how can I dynamically add **MODULENAME** ?

Comment: If you apply the script to every module I don't think you need the `app:` prefix. Did you try running it without the prefix?

Comment: You don't have to add it if you have it the every module, that's true. But if you extract task to another file and you apply it to anothers module build.gradle, you have to add otherwise you get exception that "Task with path not exists in the module XXX".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the simplest and most reliable solution ...

```
   def getModuleName() {
        return displayName.substring(displayName.indexOf(":"), displayName.length() - 1)
    }
```